# How to create Preference Activity inside Custom Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-dialog, preferenceactivity, android-dialogfragment

I have a custom dialog layout which lists the configuration items when user clicks on a button. When I press on each item from the list, it should prompt the user with another custom dialog over the existing dialog. Is it possible to do and is it possible with Preference Activity? Or should I follow any other approach apart from this?

Comment: Yeah , it is possible using Preference Activity and I guess it is the best way. You can find a good tutorial in the following link. Hope it helps you. http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create Preference Activity inside Custom Dialog in Android

A Dialog cannot contain an Activity. A Dialog can launch an Activity, but the Dialog itself cannot contain a PreferenceActivity.

I suggest using one of the many other Preference classes, like a [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html), to create the Dialog you want. But you cannot create an Activity that opens a Dialog which contains a PreferenceActivity.